# Why with "arima" function and with "Arima" get different value of MASE with accuracy?

Tags: r, series, arima, measure, forecast

Im try to calculate "manually" all the measures of accuracy and only have problems with de MASE.

Using "fit1" from arima function there is not problems, the problem is with "Arima" function.

I would like to know how calculate MASE manually with fit2 Arima object

```
fit1<-arima(EuStockMarkets[,1],order=c(1,1,0))
fit2<-Arima(EuStockMarkets[,1],order=c(1,1,0))
accuracy(fit1)
accuracy(fit2)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the MASE value from `accuracy(fit2)` either. Perhaps you can edit your post to show the manual calculation (I'm using `get_MASE <- function(fit, ts) { mae <- mean(abs(fit$residuals)); scale <- mean(abs(diff(ts))); mean(mae / scale) }` which reproduces the MASE from `accuracy(fit1)`); then perhaps raise an issue on [GH](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/issues) and link to this post.

Comment: PS. I've fixed a typo in your title; I'm sure this was meant to say MASE instead of MAPE.

Comment: I did the same thing than you and thank you for your fix